# Are there any workflow engines in existence that don't use BPMN and BPEL?

Tags: workflow, bpel, jbpm, business-rules, bpmn

Our business is planning on building a rather large business application with about 2000 or so users.

Many objects in the system require a mildly complex series of approvals, notifications, etc.

For various reasons, our company has decided to reject formal use of BPMN or BPEL.  What I am looking for is a workflow engine that I can pass these objects to as a means of facilitating, tracking, and managing the state of these objects.  We are implementing this project using EJB 3.1 with a WebSphere AS.

Am I correct in my understanding of a workflow engine? Everything seems tied to BPMN or BPEL...am I just missing something here as to why most solutions seem to implement BPMN or BPEL?  Some advice would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow engines typically take an active role in an enterprise architecture. They execute a declarative process model, which is basically a directed graph consisting of nodes, which represent activities or tasks and edges, which represent the control flow between these edges. Such edges can be annotated with conditions to allow for expressing conditional branching/merging. There are several modelling languages around, like YAWL, XPDL, jPDL, BPEL and BPMN 2.0, which sit on top of these abstract concepts and some syntatic, visual and functional sugar, but only the latter are official industry standards. This is important to avoid vendor locks, make models interchangeable (at least to a certain extent), supportable by experts and different tools. During runtime, process instances are created based on a process model and are executed according to the control flow defined by the model. So the engine actively navigates from one activity to the next activity and thus "orchestrates" your business logic. The main difference between BPMN 2.0 and BPEL is that BPEL is tightly coupled to Web services, i.e. business functions to be invoked by activities are supposed to be rendered as Web service. So if you want to orchestrated WS-* services, it is still the best choice since BPMN 2.0 lacks well-defined and standardized bindings to concrete service implementations. In any case, I'd strongly recommend to use one of the standardized languages since they are both broadly accepted in industry and well supported by various vendors and open source communities.

I tried to explain that in more details because I was not entirely sure about what you mean by "facilitating, tracking, and managing the state of these objects". This sounds a little bit like you are more interested in passively monitoring an object's state change as opposed to actively controlling state changes using a workflow engine. If this assumption is right, then perhaps a abstract state machine would fit your needs better.

Comment: Thanks Vanto!  This is exactly what I needed to hear.  It most certainly does sound like we need to roll our own state machine and perhaps tie it in with a rules engine, but I've heard you should never use a rules engine for workflow related things, so perhaps I'll avoid that combination.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Regarding the combination of rule engine and workflow engine: it depends. I usually recommend to combine them when a process has a bunch of decisions to make and the decision rules are rather complex and should not be hard-coded in the process model. So a rule of thumb could be: Use a workflow engine for control flow related things and a rule engine for data flow/data driven decisions. Don't use rules for artificially modelling explicit control flow, though. If the control flow is implicit and it is the data that triggers a state change, a rule engine is your friend.

Comment: "The BPMN standard specication is relatively detailed when it comes to specifying syntactic constraints on BPMN models, but it is unsystematic and sometimes inconsistent when it comes to dening their
semantics. The lack of formal semantics of BPMN hinders on the development of tool support for checking the correctness of BPMN models from a semantic perspective." [source](http://eprints.qut.edu.au/7115/1/7115.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jBPM5, it provides a very flexible core that allows you to build your own domain specific language on top of it. Right now the language provided is BPMN2, but you can easily add your own.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We are building a product that has a migration path for BPMN 2.0 but does not - internally, use BPMN. We believe checklists are much easier to use in real-time workflows than flowcharts. Is still however, has rules/triggers/conditionals and more - so it's a tool that effectively models processes as "checklists on steroids":

Check it out at http://tallyfy.com